# link_to_unless_current method without Rails

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm creating a site using a small Ruby framework, Sinatra, but I would like to be able to do something like what the Rails `link_to_unless_current` method does, without using Rails.

Now I have my own `link_to` method, which works the same as the Rails one, more or less, so how would I go about doing the `_unless_current` part?

Comment: Yes, but the Rails code doesn't explain how to check the link URL with the current page URL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as how you mentioned your `link_to` method is similar to the Rails one, give this a try:

```
def link_to_unless_current(text, location)
  if request.path_info == location
    text
  else
    link_to text, location
  end
end
```

I gave this a quick test and worked perfectly for me, however if your `link_to` method takes more parameters, it's pretty simple to add more, just add them to the `_unless_current(text, location, param1, param2, etc)` and the `link_to text, location, param1, param2, etc` parts of the code.

Comment: Oh, I see, `request.path_info` is the way to get the current page URL, thank you. This method worked, thank you.